# Set width of element to min-content only if the content wraps?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following CSS:

```
.tag {
  /* width: min-content; */
    display: inline-flex;
    border: 1px solid rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.45);
    padding: 2px 4px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 90%;
    margin: 0px 6px 3px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

In the first image, the first block has extra leading whitespace that I want to get rid of.
[image]

Setting

```
width: min-content
```

causes the last block to wrap, even though it could fit on one line

[image]

Comment: you cannot do this